# WSO2IS - Multiple Logouts from Multiple Service Providers

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I have two Service Providers that login to WSO2 simultaneously. For reasons that I won't explain, one of the SPs *cannot* implement Single Logout at this time.

As a result, if SP-1 logs out, WSO2 invalidates the SessionIndex, as expected.

Then, when SP-2 tries to logout (***using the same SessionIndex***) WSO2 serves up an error-page.

By tracking the requests/responses in my browser's debugger, I can see that a SAML error-response was created by WSO2. However, instead of sending the response back to the Service Provider (where it could be consumed), it just serves up the error-page and attaches the response to it.

I would like my Service Provider to receive this response so I can perform cleanup operations, and also have finer-grained control over the logging/display of errors. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have tww SPs (SP1, SP2), and if you have enabled SLO for both SPs.
Then If you logout from SP1 it will send SLO request to SP2, SLO response to SP1 and invalidate the IDP session.
So in your implementation if SP2 gets SLO request it should invalidate its session. Then it works fine.
But what you do is after SP1 initiated a SLO. again SP2 try to initiate SLO.
So better to handle it as I suggested.

Comment: As I said, one of the service providers (let's say SP2) cannot implement SLO (it is outside of our control at the moment). SLO works fine from SP2 -> SP1, but the opposite cannot work. Therefore, I'd like to receive and consume the error-response from WSO2, instead of it displaying its own error page.